# ELB & IIS host names

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS. I looked for an answer everywhere but couldn't find it.

I have :

- 1 Elastic Load Balancer setup
- 1 Elastic IP
- 2 EC2 instances (windows and IIS)

I have done the following:

- setup the 2 instances
- setup 1 elastic ip with hosted zones
- changed DNS on my domain name to point to my Route 53 hosted zones
- created a wwww CNAME to point to my ELB DNS
- A record of my domain name points to the Elastic IP

If I try to access my domain on each instance (elastic ip) it works. But if I try to access the domain name behind the load balancer, it shows me my default IIS domain name.

Basically my host names on IIS are completely ignored.

How can I make my domain point to the the correct host name behind my ELB?

I repeat, I'm new to this, so please be indulgent.

Thanks

UPDATED

Although the approved solution helped I found another one. In the bindings settings of a website in IIS, if you want a non default domain name to point to your load balancer, select "all unassigned" instead of a specific IP.

Comment: What A record did you set to your Elastic IP? Root domain (eg. example.com) or subdomain (eg. www.example.com)?

Comment: When you installed your app in IIS, did you create a new website, or did you install it under the default website?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Matt, I did not know you could set an A record to an elastic IP. I selected a network interface and an instance. 

For our second comment, I created a new website. And left the default website active so that my load balancer can check the health of the instance.

Jennie

Comment: You said in your question "A record points to the Elastic IP". If you didn't set an A record to an elastic IP, what does this statement mean then?

Comment: For the new website you installed under, what domain/IP does it respond to? The one that works for the ELB or the Elastic IP?

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't clear. I set the A name of my domain name to point to the Elastic IP I setup. I also added a CNAME on my domain name to point to the DNS of my load balancer.

Comment: In IIS, I used the private IP of the Elastic IP. Oh I think that might be where the problem is right? But I cannot enter the DNS of the load balancer. What IP should I put there? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your configuration, but I think the problem is rooted in the fact that your website is configured under a **second** website in IIS.

Under this configuration, the ELB connections are probably going to the default website (which you said you left as default). Whereas, when you connect directly to the EC2 instance, it goes to your new website.

There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Put your website under the default website in IIS. This way, all requests go to the single website. Or
2. Configure your second website to respond to your domain (example.com and www.example.com). When you make requests through ELB and directly to the EC2 instance, use these same domains.

If you must keep the second website, go with #2, but I recommend using the default website.

Comment: Oh my!!! I understand what you're saying. Before I approve your answer I have this question: Does 1. mean that I have to redirect users to a specific subfolder (using url rewrite)? Because I don't see how I can put my website under the default one. But my website is in a subfolder of the default website. Btw, I don't need to keep the second website.

Comment: You can use url rewrite to use the subfolder. But I would put it right under wwwroot.

Comment: I do host more than one websites on it.

Comment: Can you please tell me why IIS host names do not work with the load balancer? Why does it only go to the default website?

Comment: It should. Make sure your website is configured to respond to the correct host(s).

Comment: Your answer did solve my problem therefore I approved it. Thanks a lot for this. But I would really like to know how to configure the website to respond to the correct hosts. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: I found the solution. In bindings in IIS, the IP address should be "all unassigned" instead of a specific IP.